# How to read .odt using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to read ".odt" files using python with "odfpy" library, but it still doesn't work.

How can I read an ".odt" file using Python?

Answer (score 14):

First install [odfpy](https://pypi.org/project/odfpy/) library then,

```
In [21]: from odf import text, teletype
    ...: from odf.opendocument import load
    ...: 
    ...: textdoc = load("your.odt")
    ...: allparas = textdoc.getElementsByType(text.P)
    ...: teletype.extractText(allparas[0])
    ...: 
Out[21]: 'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why did you choose allparas as your variable?

Comment: Hi @Arya, allparas is just a variable name, which returns all paragraphs in .odt file.

Comment: Yes I get that, I just wanted to know what the meaning behind the name you chose.

Comment: @Arya The array allparas refers to every element in the variable textdoc of type p, that is every paragraph of the odt file. Hence, the name allparas makes sense, because it contains all the paragraphs in consideration.

Comment: is there any way to getElementByType(image)?

Comment: How to extract a maths formula object?