# Python - \x characters while reading from an uploaded file

Tags: python, django, xml

I am using python3.6 and django 2.2.6 in the backend. I am uploading a .odt file without any encoding. When I do this

```
print(type(request.FILES['labfile']))
print(request.FILES['labfile'].read())
```

It gives me
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
And this: https://pastebin.com/4WiueuMb

The original contents of the odt file is https://pastebin.com/6qT1XWJR

I tried doing
`request.FILES['labfile'].read().decode("utf-8")` 
and I got **'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 12: invalid continuation byte**

I thought \x could mean hex and tried decoding using .decode("hex") and codecs.decode() but that didn't work either.
Now it seems like the data is somehow related to xml, but I am not having any idea of how to decode.

Any leads are highly appreciated and thankful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.odt` is a file format, not just a textfile with some particular encoding. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054770/how-to-read-odt-using-python

Comment: @GordonAitchJay We are migrating from python2 to python3 and I see that this code in python2 with some older version of django is working perfectly fine. Can you please tell me what could be the reason for not working in python3?

Comment: I don't understand what you are expecting this code to do. Are you saying you think this line `print(request.FILES['labfile'].read())` will print the _original contents of the odt file_ https://pastebin.com/6qT1XWJR? Do you want that as a `str`?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay sorry for the delayed response. Yes, I want the original contents of the odt file as str. Am I missing something sir?

Comment: Use the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055187/3589122), except instead of passing it a filename, pass it a `io.BytesIO` object that has been initialised with the `.odt` data (`request.FILES['labfile'].read()`).

Comment: What I still don't understand is that your code supposedly worked in Python 2. I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Sure sir. I will try that and get back. I am also unable to understand that because after upgrading python and django, the python read method is returning a bytes object with \x characters whereas previously in python2 and a bit old django, it returned a bytes object with the exact contents of the file.